# Phpexcel can't write to xls 97-2003 format

Tags: phpexcel

```
                <?
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("../../ruw/myfile.xlsx");
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;


 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A5",$m5);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B5",$m1);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:L300')->
    getProtection()->setHidden(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::OTECTION_PROTECTED);

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertColumns(true);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatColumns(true);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setDeleteColumns(true);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setDeleteRows(true);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSelectLockedCells(true);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword($passy);


    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

   $d =$m1;
   $d = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9%$#@*&^-_()]/','',$m1);
   $fil = "../../ruw/".$d.".xlsx";
   $objWriter->save($fil);

    echo "<label style='font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#CE0000'>
    File download start automatically if not click here to </label>&nbsp;";
    echo "<a  style='font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; font-weight:bold;'   href='$fil'>Download</a>&nbsp;";
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" ;
    echo "reply_click(".$_SESSION['mid'].",'$fil')";
    echo "</script>";
    ?>
```

This code is working fine to write on ".xlsx" but not working to write no ".xls"

if i try to write and open .xls i am getting different format,unreadable content and xml parse arror

i want to write to .xls 97-2003 and save it as .xls 97-2003 format

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may have a problem with `OTECTION_PROTECTED`, but that should be giving you a warning message

Comment: Yes its large file and has 10 sheet each of them has 80 formulas

Comment: If your formulae contain reference to functions that didn't exists in MS EXcel prior to Excel 2007, then they will cause problems.... the Excel5 Writer only supports functions that were available in core MS Excel

Comment: Thanks Yes its not carrying most of the formula since  i have change the format to excel 2007 and tried to write every thing working fine but this is happening please check the link  http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=6ec7374

Comment: Perhaps knowing what I need to do to create a script that replicates this issue might help me find a solution to it

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong `Writer` instance you need to change `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007` to `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5()`

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("myfile.xls");
```

**Note:** You will need to update your include path accordingly.

Comment: Yes its correct but after saving the file its not carrying the formula